# How to skip validations for embedded models when we save model that embeds them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have model Book which embeds many documents and articles. Models Document and Article have some validations. My goal is to skip validations for all embedded models when I save a model which embeds them. In my case I want to skip validations for documents and articles when I save a book(but don't skip them for the book). Is it possible? 
Here's a snip of code

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name

  embeds_many :documents
  embeds_many :articles

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Document
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name

  embedded_in :book

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name

  embedded_in :book

  validates :name, presence: true
end

b = Book.new
b.name = 'super book'
b.documents = [Document.new]
b.articles = [Article.new, Article.new]
b.save
```

So I want this method 'save' not to run validations for embedded documents and articles, only for book. This should save the book, even if I don't have names for documents and articles.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, perhaps due to terminology. Rails doesn't have any notion of “embedding documents”, for example. Can you please clarify, perhaps providing code you're working with?

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `validate: false` in your model definition

```
embeds_many :documents, validate: false 
embeds_many :articles, validate: false
```

Comment: This will not run validations for all models. I want them to run only for main model, not for embedded models.

Comment: How about `embeds_many :documents, validate: false` `embeds_many :articles, validate: false`?